# C++ How to fix bug of not clearing an input vector if it is the same as the output one?

Tags: c++, vector

I have a function that has two vector parameters. It takes just some elements from the "*input vector*" and add them to the "*output vector*". It looks like this:

```
void foo(const std::vector< MyObj >& myObjsIn, std::vector< MyObj >& myObjsOut)
{
  for (size_t i = 0; i < myObjsIn.size(); i++)
  {
    if (myObjsIn[i].condition())
    {
      myObjsOut.push_back(myObjsIn[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

But there is a bug if I give the same vector as input and output (It is adding the chosen elements at the end of the vector). If I add a clear of the output one, it will clear the input one (for the specified case), too; so I am getting an empty vector. I thought of:

```
void foo(const std::vector< MyObj >& myObjsIn, std::vector< MyObj >& myObjsOut)
{
  std::vector< MyObj > tmpObjs = myObjsIn;
  myObjsOut.clear();

  for (size_t i = 0; i < tmpObjs.size(); i++)
  {
    if (tmpObjs[i].condition())
    {
      myObjsOut.push_back(tmpObjs[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

But is it ok to copy the input vector to a temporary one and the clearing the output one? Is it nicer to return the output vector and create a temporary vector where to add the chosen elements? Like this:

```
std::vector< MyObj > foo(const std::vector< MyObj >& myObjsIn)
{
  std::vector< MyObj > tmpObjs;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < myObjsIn.size(); i++)
  {
    if (tmpObjs[i].condition())
    {
      tmpObjs.push_back(myObjsIn[i]);
    }
  }
  return tmpObjs;
}
```

Or what do you suggest me to do, for fixing that bug and optimize my code?

Comment: The last version is the nicest. You even can "simplify" the implementation by using `std::copy_if`.

Comment: What exactly is the bug with your original solution?  You wrote a function that takes elements from what vector that meet a condition and add them to a second vector.  How is it a bug that those elements that meet the condition get added to the end of the output vector?  Are you trying to avoid duplicates?

Comment: No, not avoiding duplicates. The bug is the call `foo(vec1, vec1);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you stick with a single-purpose function as in your question, your final answer seems to be pretty reasonable. However an alternative would be temp-then-swap:

```
void foo(const std::vector< MyObj >& myObjsIn, std::vector< MyObj >& myObjsOut)
{
  std::vector< MyObj > tmpObjs;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < myObjsIn.size(); i++)
  {
    if (myObjsIn[i].condition())
    {
      tmpObjs.push_back(myObjsIn[i]);
    }
  }
  myObjsOut.swap(tmpObjs);
}
```

A potentially more elegant solution would be to utilize `boost::filter_iterator` (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/iterator/doc/filter_iterator.html) and then you could simply use two filter iterators in the ranged-constructor to your new `vector`.

The (untested) code would look something like this (will try to compile later when I get a moment):

```
struct execute_condition
{
    bool operator()(const MyObj& obj) const { return obj.condition(); }
};

std::vector filtered_objects(boost::make_filter_iterator<execute_condition>(myObjsIn.begin(), myObjsIn.end()), boost::make_filter_iterator<execute_condition>(myObjsIn.end(), myObjsIn.end()));
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to return the vector instead, so no more swap thing? Or you think it is slower to return object than swap?

Comment: I prefer the return by value or the filter iterator. I was simply providing an alternate mechanism if you didn't have the luxury of changing the function signature.

Answer (score 0):

Since you call push_back on the output vector, the only you should change is the stop condition in the loop, so you will eliminate infinite run and stay with original functionality

```
void foo(const std::vector< MyObj >& myObjsIn, std::vector< MyObj >& myObjsOut)
{
  size_t inSize = myObjsIn.size();
  for (size_t i = 0; i < inSize; i++)
  {
    if (myObjsIn[i].condition())
    {
      myObjsOut.push_back(myObjsIn[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: As I have mentioned: the problem is when calling `foo(vec1, vec1)`. It will add the chosen elements at the end of the `vec1`.

Comment: Is there an infinite loop that I have not seen?!